# Android share multiple intent to the target app (like whatsapp) sequencially, all of them just with choose target app once

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I know i can put multiple extra (image + text) in an intent like the following codes and send the intent to the target app:

```
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

But i want **share 3 different type of content** by 3 intent:

1. First a Text (`text/plain`)
2. Then an Image (`image/*`)
3. And then a Video (`video/*`)

into the choosen app by user (specialy some apps like `Whatsapp`, `Viber`, `Telegram`), sequentially but in separate messages.

For example:

1. The user clicks on `Share Button`
2. My App show her/him the list of Apps (`Whatsapp`,...)
3. Then the user choose an App
4. Now i want share 3 different intent (with 3 different type: `text/plain` | `image/*` | `video/*`) to the selected App.

---

I currently in my solution share 3 different content with **3 different share command**, so finally i forced to call 3 time this code:

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, chooserTitle));
```

**But** i want know can i **share multiple intent** just with show **`Choose app dialog` once**.

Comment: did you tried this, setting the setType to */* ? does it helps you?

Comment: do you got it worked?